# Using a trademark name

Tags: copyright, sfx

Hi everyone,
As some of you may remember I am completing an SFX library based around a car. Now has come the time to get the artwork done, but I'm not sure what I'm legally able to call the pack!

All of the sounds are from a Renault Clio, but is there any way to say that without being in breach of copyright?

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

So I contacted a Solicitor who basically said it was a grey area and said fairly much the same as Chuck. So I contacted Renault, and they said that they will give me permission to use the name for a limited time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure that you are violating trademark by recording a car and releasing the collection named after the source.  But I'm just a sound guy, so what do I know.  You have 3 options:

1. Contact an attorney who has a good understanding of trademark law who can offer you proper legal guidance on this.  This is the best way to go, as a good attorney is more qualified than you or anyone on this forum to answer your questions.  They could also help you seek license to use the name of the car, should you choose to go that route.
2. Don't use the name of the car in any way.
3. Use the name and don't worry about it.  It's possible someday, you might get a cease and desist notice and then you can change the name of the library.  Our sound effects libraries do not have a very high visibility outside of our little sound world.  Chances are, you'll never run into issue.

If it were me, I'd go with option 1 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

From memory, trademarks are specific to the market of the products they're associated with. In theory, this would mean that since an SFX library is not a car, naming the library after the car would not be violating trademark. Similarly, if you were to create a brand of cheese and name it "Toyota," you'd theoretically be in the clear.

On the other hand, the law can be a tricky thing. I advise you to consult an expert in that field, rather than strangers you met on the internet.

Comment: Thanks Chuck/ Joseph. This sounds promising, I will get in touch with a lawyer and report back with my findings..